# Trying to run a code in Haskell ..errors

Tags: haskell

I am a newb at haskell and I am trying to run the code for data mining in haskell from https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2016/09/data-haskell 
But it does not work at all.... I even tried the below code with these imports
`import Control.Monad.Except`
`import Control.Monad.State`,
still does not work.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications, OverloadedStrings, OverloadedLabels,
  TypeOperators, DataKinds, FlexibleContexts #-}
import Labels.RunResourceT

main =
 runResourceT $
 httpSource "http://chrisdone.com/ontime.csv.zip" responseBody .|
 zipEntryConduit "ontime.csv" .|
 fromCsvConduit
   @("fl_date" := Day, "tail_num" := String)
   (set #downcase True csv) .|
 dropConduit 10 .|
 takeConduit 5 .>
 tableSink
```

This is the error

```
Prelude> :l haskell-tut
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( haskell-tut.hs, interpreted )

haskell-tut.hs:3:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for `Labels.RunResourceT'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I would appreciate if any of you can provide the imports or modules to be used and even how to use it too!
I even tried:

```
import Control.Monad.Except 
import Control.Monad.State
```

still errors
tried this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications, OverloadedStrings, OverloadedLabels, TypeOperators, DataKinds, FlexibleContexts #-}

import Labels.Explore

main =
 runResourceT $
 httpSource "http://chrisdone.com/ontime.csv.zip" responseBody .|
 zipEntryConduit "ontime.csv" .|
 fromCsvConduit
   @("fl_date" := Day, "tail_num" := String)
   (set #downcase True csv) .|
 dropConduit 10 .|
 takeConduit 5 .>
 tableSink
```

as suggested in the Github Repository does not work!
Error is :

```
Prelude> :load haskell-tut
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( haskell-tut.hs, interpreted )

haskell-tut.hs:3:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for `Labels.Explore'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Tried the entire Github Code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications, OverloadedStrings, OverloadedLabels,
  TypeOperators, DataKinds, FlexibleContexts #-}

import Labels.Explore

moo1 :: IO ()
moo1 =
  runResourceT $
  httpSource "http://chrisdone.com/ontime.csv.zip" responseBody .|
  zipEntryConduit "ontime.csv" .|
  fromCsvConduit
    @("fl_date" := Day, "tail_num" := String)
    (set #downcase True csv) .|
  dropConduit 10 .|
  takeConduit 5 .>
  tableSink

moo_write :: IO ()
moo_write =
  runResourceT
    (httpSource "http://chrisdone.com/ontime.csv.zip" responseBody .|
     zipEntryConduit "ontime.csv" .>
     fileSink "ontime.csv")

moo1_1 :: IO ()
moo1_1 =
  runResourceT $
  fileSource "ontime.csv" .|
  fromCsvConduit
    @("distance" := Double)
    (set #downcase True csv) .|
  sinkConduit
    (foldSink
       (\table row ->
          modify #flights (+ 1) (modify #distance (+ get #distance row) table))
       (#flights := (0 :: Int), #distance := 0)) .>
  tableSink

moo2 :: IO ()
moo2 =
  runResourceT $
  fileSource "ontime.csv" .|
  fromCsvConduit
    @("fl_date" := Day, "tail_num" := String, "airline_id" := Int, "unique_carrier" := String)
    (set #downcase True csv) .|
  groupConduit #airline_id .|
  explodeConduit .|
  projectConduit @("fl_date" := _, "unique_carrier" := _) .|
  takeConduit 5 .>
  tableSink

moo3 :: IO ()
moo3 =
  runResourceT $
  fileSource "ontime.csv" .|
  fromCsvConduit
    @("fl_date" := Day, "tail_num" := String, "airline_id" := Int, "unique_carrier" := String)
    (set #downcase True csv) .|
  groupConduit #airline_id .|
  explodeConduit .|
  dropConduit 10 .|
  projectConduit @("fl_date" := _, "tail_num" := _) .|
  takeConduit 5 .>
  tableSink

main = moo1_1
```

Still getting the below error!

```
Prelude> :load haskell-tut
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( haskell-tut.hs, interpreted )

haskell-tut.hs:4:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for `Labels.Explore'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Please help!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I think the article is not showing all imports. Conduit imports, at least, are missing.

Comment: Posted the error now.....I don't know how to use "-v" indicated too....yes the tutorial is kind of incomplete........

Comment: It seems you are supposed to use this program with the [`Labels.Explore`](https://github.com/chrisdone/labels/blob/master/labels-explore/src/Labels/Explore.hs) module in the GitHub repository mentioned in the tutorial (@Jean-BaptistePotonnier : that module reexports the relevant *conduit* stuff). I have no idea why the snippet in the tutorial uses `import Labels.RunResourceT` rather than `import Labels.Explore`.

Comment: yeah @dulpode, I've just noticed it. Maybe the best way is to check out https://github.com/chrisdone/labels/tree/master/labels-explore and compile with cabal. I think tutorials should be more beginner friendly, and explain how to run the example. I suffered from this before, and particularly from people using only unqualified imports !

Comment: Done......does not work tried copy pasting the entire github code too....does not work......pasted everything ....

Comment: Maybe you can try to check out https://github.com/chrisdone/labels and compile with stack.

Comment: Note that this is actually a really quite advanced application, involving cutting-edge compiler extensions and rather heavyweight libraries. Not necessarily a good place for starting with a programming language like Haskell...

Comment: I fixed the tutorial content, thanks! @ShreyaChakrabarti Try cloning git@github.com:chrisdone/labels.git and run `stack build`. This file https://github.com/chrisdone/labels/blob/master/labels-explore/app/Main.hs you can edit to play around.